# Done button in abpersonviewcontroller not saving ios

Tags: ios, abpersonviewcontroller

When i hit done in the edit mode of the person view controller it doesn't save to the address book. It goes to the previous screen and shows the new data. However in the contact app nothing changed.

```
 -(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{


    ABPersonViewController *
    vcPerson = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    if([self.peopleProperty objectForKey:@"phone_number"]!=nil)
    {
        NSString* phoneNumber = [self.peopleProperty objectForKey:@"phone_number"];

         ABMultiValueRef multiVal = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(multiVal);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone,(__bridge CFTypeRef)(phoneNumber), kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone, &error);
        CFRelease(multiPhone);
        CFRelease(multiVal);
    }


    vcPerson.allowsActions = NO;
    vcPerson.allowsEditing = YES;
    vcPerson.displayedPerson = person;
    vcPerson.personViewDelegate = self;
    [vcPerson setEditing:YES animated:NO];
    vcPerson.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back",nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ReturnFromPersonView:)];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcPerson animated:YES];



    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
    return NO;}
```

**Update**
I figured that apparently you cant change the value in displayed person before the view controller loads. It doesn't recognise that as a change in the contact once it tries to save later on.

Comment: Share some of controller code or something, we can't help you if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: sorry about that. added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that apparently you cant change the value in displayed person before the view controller loads. It doesn't recognise that as a change in the contact once it tries to save later on